# Include text from another cell in to formula

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to create a sheet to make it easy to view a certain set of data for my employees. My current formula works and is follows:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("linktoothergooglesheet","sheetname!A1:AE61")
```

What I would like to do is type the sheetname in cell A1 and have the formula draw the sheet name from here. This way when the staff are changing what they want to look at, they just change the name in cell A1 rather than edit the formula - is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Got there with some help from a friend - substituting the sheetname for “&A1&” didn’t work when I first tried it, but now seems to be working fine